# Cook chickpeas directly in soup?

Tags: soup, beans, pressure-cooker, instant-pot

I just started cooking dried chickpeas in my pressure cooker. It made me wonder... I have some soup recipes that I make in my IP that call for canned chick peas. At first I was subbing in my cooked chickpeas. Is there any reason I can't just add my already-soaked chickpeas directly to the soup? The soup will be cooking at pressure for at least as long as my chickpeas recipe calls for anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why not.

I make channa masala from scratch - fry onions, garlic, chilli, add spices, drop soaked chickpeas
...and enough extra water so it will absorb and evaporate in the required time.

That's your only bit of guesswork, but for soup that's probably not as crucial as for a dish which is served almost dry.

What may be your sticking point -  you may have to salt towards the end, or they will be tough. As I don't pressure-cook, I'm not sure how easy that would be. For regular stove-top, it would be 30 minutes before the end of a 2-hour cook.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try next time I'm making the soup. Good point about the salt.